# Return the difference between the largest and smallest values

Tags: python, list, sorting, input

Given an array length 1 or more of ints, return the difference between the largest and smallest values in the list. Note: I don't want to use min and max function.. [10,3,5,6] - 7 , [7,2,10,9] - 8

```
our_list = []
numbers=int(input("enter numbers").strip()) 
our_list.append(numbers) 
our_list.sort() 
print (our_list)
```

Here is my logic, first I will display the list of the inputted value and then I will use sort method to sort the list to find the min and max number from the list and then I will deduct from the max to min number but I am not able to achieve the result, Here is my code so far..

The above code is not even sorting the numbers thus not able to move ahead,  please help.

Comment: `numbers=int(input("enter numbers").strip())` is not doing at all what i think you think it is doing. I would recommend looking at [string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) and [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) documentation to better understand

Comment: @Sam ok sure, I am going to read that again

Comment: @martineau because I am learning and I want to explore different ways to achieve the results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is you need to split by whitespace (or another delimiter) in order for a user to submit multiple numbers via a single `input`.

Since `str.split()` splits by whitespace and returns a `list`, you can `map` each element to `int` and pass to `sorted`. Here's an example:

```
# retrieve string input
input_str = input('Enter numbers separated by whitespace:\n')

# split by whitespace, convert to integer, then sort
numbers = sorted(map(int, input_str.split()))

# calculate difference between last and first items
res = numbers[-1] - numbers[0]

# display / print result  
print(res)
```

Comment: I got the desired result, however I have to understand more about map function :-)

Answer (score 0):

A variation in your approach could be using an endless loop in which numbers are input until 'exit' typed by the user.

```
our_list = []
i = 0
while i>= 0:
    numbers = input("enter numbers") 
    if numbers == 'exit':
        break
    our_list.append(int(numbers)) 
print our_list.sort()
```